# (OpenCV with Python) Undesired autorotation behaviour when using VideoCapture(1) / External webcam

Tags: python, opencv, rotation, video-capture, gopro

I am trying to display my Webcam's (a GoPro 8) video onto the computer with OpenCV, but I do not want the autorotation feature -- by that I mean when I shift from holding the GoPro from landscape to portrait (say rotated 90degree), I want the displayed image on my computer to show the rotated view in landscape.

[Image displayed on computer when held on Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBTUV.jpg)

[Image displayed on computer when held on Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA54T.jpg)

So the above two photo shows what is does right now, but I want it to look like the below.
[Ideal image displayed on computer when held on Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Elg3o.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cv2.namedWindow("window", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty("window",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

while(True):
   ret, frame = video.read()
   if ret == True:
      flipped = cv2.flip(frame, 1) #flip frame vertically, I want it flipped for other reasons
      cv2.imshow('window', flipped)
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q') :
      break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Is there any way I can ignore the orientation of the external webcam? I tried rotating the images with cv2.rotate() but it is not what I want.

Comment: eventually you can compare `height > width` to recognize `portrait` and then rotate it with `cv2.rotate()`

Comment: it seem cv2 has property [CAP_PROP_ORIENTATION_META](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ggaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704da161e0ba8e8fad2a34880e0fc6753a2b2) but I don't know if it gives information about camer rotation. But even if it gives information about rotation then you would still need to use `cv2.rotate()`

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution is using cv2.rotate in this way you can get your desired output. Btw I'm using a Logitech 720p webcam and when I put it in portrait position it gives me your desired output without using any python function and here is code for your output using cv2.rotate ()

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture (0)

width = 400
height = 350

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (width, height))
    flipped = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    framerot = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)
    framerot = cv2.resize(framerot, (width, height))
    StackImg = np.hstack([frame, flipped, framerot])
    cv2.imshow("ImageStacked", StackImg)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks, you made me realize it could very well be the problem with the GoPro internally flipping the image instead.

Comment: I'm glad that you get some help :)